# image reset after transform css

Tags: html, css

I want a growing effect on hover to my div
my div code

```
<div class="CastData">
    <a href="Artist.php?ArtistID=0000701" >
        <div class="CastImage">
           <img src="Public/Cast/0000701 - Kate Winslet.jpg" width="40" height="40" />
       </div>          
       <div class="CastName">
           Kate Winslet
     </a>
     <br />
     <small>Jeanine</small></div>
</div>
```

this is my css code

```
.CastImage, .CastName{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.CastImage img{
    border-radius:100%;
}

.CastData{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    }

.CastData > * {
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.CastData:hover > *{
    padding-right:10px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

when I hover on my div, every thing grows, and then text remains big on hover, and image resets itself to previous size, why? 
**Ignore my link attribute, which is closing in middle of div, I want only real name and image as link, and cast name as simple text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small glitch but try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/1bz5ag5z/1/)

```css
.CastImage, .CastName{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.CastImage img{
    border-radius:100%;
}

.CastData{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    }

.CastData > * {
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.CastData:hover  *{
    padding-right:10px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="CastData">
    <a href="Artist.php?ArtistID=0000701" >
        <div class="CastImage">
           <img src="Public/Cast/0000701 - Kate Winslet.jpg" width="40" height="40" />
       </div>          
       <div class="CastName">
           Kate Winslet
     </a>
     <br />
     <small>Jeanine</small></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked, thanks, and can you tell me why my image is increasing its size a little bit more during transform than its expected size?

Comment: @SyedTalhahai That glith is because you used `scale` images will always have a glitch

Comment: one more problem, when I hover on elements they grows radily, I want smooth growing like this site http://xaviesteve.com/

Comment: so what should i do? remove height and width?

Comment: @SyedTalhahai Just a minute let me try something

Comment: it was growing well with .CastData:hover > * but with this line image was resetting itself, you code is preventing imge to reset but image grows radily

Comment: @SyedTalhahai Somethings messing it up just a minute

Comment: your pen code is the thing I want, but is it possible to do this without js?

Comment: @SyedTalhahai Yes i used js to add a class that's all the rest is css

Comment: @SyedTalhahai The class `.big` is the one you want try your code with that

Comment: still same problem, rapid growing on hover, and image is gorwing little bit more, than shrinks to expected size

Comment: may be this is blurring when growing, can i prevent it from blurring?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73563/discussion-between-syed-talha-hai-and-akshay).

Comment: your first code is working now :) i changed .CastData > * to .CastData  *, and this is growing smoothly

Comment: Okay glad you found it out @SyedTalhahai

Answer (score 1):

You are missing

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

property in your css. Try it in :hover pseudo class and let me know if it made it.

Comment: Strange... [link to working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm7j0hhz/) What browser are you using? Can you update the fiddle with your example?

Comment: updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/jm7j0hhz/2/ I want smooth growing of image, like the text is growing in this fiddle

Comment: Hey! You have it ;) Just one minor thing! Note that on your fiddle in the first style you have
".CastData > *" try to remove ">" as the img element is deeper in the document structure than 1 level.

Comment: Try this;
https://jsfiddle.net/3r41kynf/
I've added back ">" becouse without it, if the element is third child, it will scale 3 times! And also use scale3d for better performance. By using this you are sure gpu is used to do some rendering. 

All in all I would do it in different way; instead of img use div with background image, and background-size:cover. Then scale it. Try some things, now I need to go work, in the evening I will paste you some nice styled fiddle.

Comment: Ahh.. and it seems that chrome has some problems when you try to transfrom "small" html tag. Use some span with class for it instead.